# Suddenly ubuntu 22.04 is starting without graphics

Tags: nvidia, graphics, 22.04

I rebooted Ubuntu 22.04, and suddenly it starts without graphics
I can only see the login prompt is black.
I tried to switch terminals `CTRL + ALT + F1--F6`,but getting the same terminal

I tried to run `startx` and got this message
[image]

Comment: Any chance you shut it down with the power button or there was a powerless last shutdown? What was the last thing you did before you shut down the OS?

Comment: well I powered off normally. it's just I tried to remove python3.10.

Comment: Then you killed the OS. Ubuntu needs and uses for many of its features the version of Python it ships with. Time to re install from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

If you still have command-line, you reinstall python, upgrade, reboot, and see what happens. If it's the same, the next command to try is xinit. Please come back to tell us the error message if xinit returns one.